# Does the new spoiler code work?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, spoilers

I tried editing a question earlier, to implement [the new spoiler code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers), and ran into some troubles.  I'll be using this thread to test my usage of that code to make sure I'm doing it right - instead of messing with any more threads in the parent site.

This is a spoiler:

> Hello!  I'm a spoiler!

This is a really long spoiler:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

These are two adjacent spoiler paragraphs:

> ! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
>
> ! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Looks like there may indeed be something broken with the feature.  Added the bug tag to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> for a hard refresh to get the new code into your local cache.

> It worked for me!

---

```
>! although the two next to each other in your question body  

>! still do not get hidden while they are separated by a line...
```

creates:

> ! although the two next to each other in your question body
>
> ! still do not get hidden while they are separated by a line...

---

```
>! but maybe if I try  
>!  
>! to link them together
```

> but maybe if I try
>
>  to link them together, it will work.

Comment: Right.  This is why I added the bug tag.  It's working, but apparently broken for "special" cases.

Comment: Did you copy GraceNote's idea from the other thread, or did it go the other way around?  ;-)

Comment: Independently! My edit precedes her post by 48 seconds... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

It works now.  I spoilered [How to fix this scenario for D&D Encounters?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/how-to-fix-this-scenario-for-dd-encounters).

Comment: It's still part-broken though, as seen in my question post.  You bypassed the issue by combining the two paragraphs.

Comment: @Iszi I agree, but I think combining paragraphs is an acceptable workaround in this case.

Comment: I disagree.  There's a reason paragraphs exist in the written human languages, and they are far from being an uncommon method for arranging text.  The code should not be accepted as broken for those cases.

Comment: @Iszi I meant in the case of that specific question.

Comment: @CRoss - I see.  Went ahead and fixed the paragraphs with GraceNote's workaround from the other thread, though.

Comment: @Iszi Good idea.

Answer (score -1):

It should work now; the `spoiler` CSS class was not on the metas yet.

(you may still need to hard refresh as yhw42 indicated)

Comment: It works generally, for stuff that's on one line or for contiguous paragraphs.  However, separate adjacent paragraphs break the code, as seen above.  The problem did/does not only exist on the metas either.  I only brought my testing here (as noted in my initial post) to keep the parent site clean.  The whole reason I came here was because of the same break noted above.  Please see my new thread (since I can't remove "status-completed" from this one) for more details:  http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/759/197