# Is the spoiler broken, for adjacent paragraphs?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, spoilers

Making this a new thread, since I can't remove "status-completed" from my [previous thread](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/754/197).

[The spoiler code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers) seems to work for single-line spoilers, and single-paragraph (one long line, which gets word-wrapped) spoilers, such as these.

Single line:

> Hey, I'm a spoiler!

Single paragraph:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

However, the code breaks when you have two paragraphs which are separated by a blank line, as below:

> ! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
>
> ! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

The only way to get two such paragraphs to display correctly, seems to require some non-spoiler text in between them as below:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Hi, no spoiler here!

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

I even tried using non-displayed, line-breaking code like the BR tag in between the paragraphs, to no avail.

I'm pretty sure the code should not require such separation between paragraphs.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Other notes:

- I'm running Windows XP SP3 with Firefox 3.6.12, but have had the same problem with Firefox on Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows 7, and Chrome 7.0.517.44 on XP SP 3.
- The spoiler code does not work at all for me in IE 7.0.5730.13CO on XP SP3.

**EDIT:**  [GraceNote has suggested](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/759/is-the-spoiler-broken-for-adjacent-paragraphs/760#760) using the following code, where there are two spaces inserted at the end of "First paragraph" and on the blank line between:

```
>! First paragraph  
>!  
>! Second paragraph
```

Looks like this:

> First paragraph
>
>  Second paragraph

This is a good workaround, but the issue still remains un-patched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

correct, use

```
>! First paragraph  
>!  
>! Second paragraph
```

If you want multiple paragraphs of spoiler.

Comment: Again, this is an incomplete answer which is forcing me to again create a separate thread.  My OP also notes that the spoiler text does not work in IE 7 on Windows XP SP3.  I've also just tested it on IE8 in XP SP3, and it does not work there either.

Comment: Also, I (perhaps being a minority) believe it is very counter-intuitive that blank lines should require the same code, and also that lines should have spaces at the end in order to break correctly.  Why is this "by design"?

Comment: @iszi one question per question please. the title of this question: "Is the spoiler broken for adjacent paragraphs", and I humbly submit this *is* the answer to *that* question.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of oddities that result from things that follow or precede a block quote. One of the more infamous ones is the behavior with lists.

This isn't so much a solution, but a workaround is to use the double-space single line break. You can do it once to have no space between your paragraphs, or twice like as follows.

> What's going on here?
>
>  Everything's dark!

The code for the above... well, you can't see it but the first line has 2 white space at the end, and the second line is nothing but two white space.

```
>! What's going on here?  
>!  
>! Everything's dark!
```

Now, on my screen I'm not actually seeing the spoiler format (although the ! are getting trimmed). I'm hoping it works right for you. I did test it [over on Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/716/formatting-sandbox/789#789), where it did work in this fashion. It's a pain, I won't deny that, but it's at least something to tide you over until either something changes or someone figures out a better workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround.  I'd like to see them actually fix the code, though.

Comment: @Iszi I agree, but some of the WMD syntax things are easier said than done.

Comment: nice to have you helping out here, you want my job? :-)

Comment: There's also the issue of code not working at all on IE7/XP-SP3.  But, that could just be some policy in place at work.  I'll check on another system when I can.