# Spoiler quotes aren't rendering correctly

Tags: bug, formatting, spoilers, stack-exchange

I was trying to edit this question, as it contains spoilers: [What happens in Curse of Strahd if the players destroy Strahd's coffin or prevent him from returning to it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/185492/what-happens-in-curse-of-strahd-if-the-players-destroy-strahds-coffin-or-preven)

I was just trying to hide the spoilers with >! at the beginning of each line, but I came across a problem when trying to edit a section of text that was previously in blockquotes. I've included images below showing what happened.

---

**Here's what it looks like in the editor:**

> [image: 1]

---

**...And here's what it looks like in the preview:**

> [image]

---

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?
All the other times I used `>!`, it worked just fine.

Comment: Don't edit your question to include the answer/explanation as part of it; the question should only consist of question content - something that answers/addresses/explains the issue the question is about should simply be an answer instead. (This isn't as big of a deal on Meta, but it is certainly relevant to mainsite questions - you shouldn't edit the question to include the answer, because it just gets confusing to read the Q&A.)

Comment: Note that spoiler markup is super buggy and has been known to be buggy for years: [this bug is as old as 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116613/spoilers-dont-support-block-formatting-and-so-dont-format-well). Basically spoilers _exist_ and that's about as good as we're going to get for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/759/is-the-spoiler-broken-for-adjacent-paragraphs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The linebreak before "If" breaks the spoiler markdown.

*Curse of Strahd* spoilers ahead.

> [image]

Fixed (by deleting the linebreak), it looks like:

> [image]

Alternatively, we can fix it like this:

> [image]

With a double space at the end of the first two line in the spoiler block. This is the solution I went with, as this matches the rendering in the adventure's text.

Comment: Thanks! I see you went ahead and edited the post as well, so thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

The linebreak is indeed what broke the spoiler format.

If you wish to still format these with a new-line within, simply include two spaces after the first line and readd the `>!` to the following line.

```
>!Spoilers followed by a double-space  
>!Following line after line-break
```

> Spoilers followed by a double-space
> Following line after line-break